# Why does my view function render data but it won't show up in the browser? (AJAX/Django)

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-views

I have finally achieved that my Javascript on 'click' function and AJAX work handy in collaboration with my view function that calls data from an API. But now I have one more issue:

The data from the API is forwarded smoothly to the html containers that contain the according variables. But in my browser I don't see the content being displayed?!

Why is that?

I don't have a success function set up in AJAX so far, since I understood that the view function renders the frontend so there is no need for AJAX success function in that case?

In advance thank you so much for your inputs.

**View**

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
import json


def team_update(request):
    team_id = request.GET.get('team')
    response = requests.get(f'http://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/teams/team/{team_id}')
    team_data = response.json()
    teams = team_data.get('api', {}).get('teams', [])
    if teams and len(teams) == 1:
        teams = teams[0]
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'name': teams['name'],
        'country': teams['country'],
        'founded': teams['founded'],
        'logo': teams['logo'],
        'venue_capacity': teams['venue_capacity'],
    })
```

**Javascript/Ajax:**

```
$('ul.subbar li a').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var team_id = $(this).attr("id");
console.log(team_id);
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/dashboard/",
  data: {'team': team_id},
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML (the key part):**

```
      <div class="topRow">
        <div class="team">
          <div class="teamLogo">
            <img class="teamLogo" src="{% static "images/club_flags/Clubs/Germany/FC Bayern München.png" %}" alt="Manchester United">
          </div>
          <div class="selectedClub">{{ name }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!---End of Top Row and Start of Second row--->

      <div class="secondRow">
        <div class="column">
          <p class="heading">Founded in</p>
          <p class="figure" id="founded">{{ founded }}</p>
        </div>
```

**Debug:**
[image]

Comment: You're not doing anything in the success function of your AJAX call? I expect it will log to the console with `console.log` and you have shown that in your screenshot. But it's not actually in your page, you're just logging the response.

Comment: So the console log within my success function shows the response from the view function which did send a rendered html but to really display it I have to use the success function of the AJAX function?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Depending on what your full HTML response is, and what the HTML on the page is. Very basically you would add the response HTML, to some container element, with some code like this in your success function: `document.getElementById('some-container-id').innerHTML = response`. I think in jQuery, which you appear to be using, you could do something like this `$('#some-container-id').html(response)`

Comment: Ok, I will try to figure out a solution and post it here once working. Do you have any resource of how AJAX and view function work interact? So could I say that the view function works on the server-side while AJAX is responsible for the client-side?

Comment: Although I don't have any knowledge of how Django Views works, from a cursory read it appears they are sort of "responses" to web requests. So once the web response data has been received in the browser, it is treated like any other data, there is no Django specific part about it. 

And yes, you could would be correct in saying "the view function works on the server-side while AJAX is responsible for the client-side".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to utilise the response data from within your success function, rather than simply logging it. I'll make some assumptions about your page, say for example you currently have the following

```
<body>

  <!-- all your other stuff on the page -->

  <div id="container-element">
    <div class="topRow">
      <div class="team">
        <div class="teamLogo">
          <img class="teamLogo" src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="selectedClub"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!---End of Top Row and Start of Second row--->

    <div class="secondRow">
      <div class="column">
        <p class="heading">Founded in</p>
        <p class="figure" id="founded"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If that was how your page is currently set up, then in your success function of your AJAX call, you could do this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/dashboard/",
  data: {'team': team_id },
  success: function(response) {
    $('container-element').html(response);
  }
});
```

Which will replace the content inside your actual page.